# Prolog - giving value to query variable (list recursion)

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I need to create a rule that has an input list and then takes values from it 2 at a time, compares them and creates a new list with the bigger values.

It needs to work like this:

INPUT:  `bigger([1,2,6,8,5], X).`

OUTPUT: `X = [2,6,8,8,5].`

Here's my code:

```
%stop
bigger([],_).

%last element
bigger([H1|[]],L2):-
    append(L2, [H1], L3),
    bigger([],L3).

%compare first 2
bigger([H1,H2|T], L2):-
    ( H1 > H2,
    append(L2, [H1], L3),
    bigger([H2|T], L3) )
    ;
    ( H2 > H1,
    append(L2, [H2], L3),
    bigger([H2|T], L3) ).
```

If I replace the base case with

```
 %stop
 bigger([],L):-
     write(L).
```

then I will get this output:

```
[2,6,8,8,5]
X = [] ;
[_G3685,2,6,8,8,5]
X = [_G3685] ;
[_G3685,_G3691,2,6,8,8,5]
X = [_G3685, _G3691] ;
[_G3685,_G3691,_G3697,2,6,8,8,5]
X = [_G3685, _G3691, _G3697]
.
```

I can see that at when it reaches the base case technically the second variable has the correct value. But then it unifies to an empty list. Not only that but it continues to add unknown elements.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you need to change. For example the clause :

```
bigger([H1|[]],L2):-
    append(L2, [H1], L3),
    bigger([],L3).
```

calls bigger([],L3) which matches with the clause `bigger([],_).` but `'_'` matches with anything so this gives you the unknown elements. It is not very good idea ti use append but it would be better to use pattern matching like:

```
bigger([],[]).
bigger([H],[H]).
bigger([H1,H2|T], [X|T1]):-
    ( H1 > H2->
      X=H1,
      bigger([H2|T], T1)
     ;H2 > H1->
      X=H2,
      bigger([H2|T],T1) ).
```

here you instantiate one element of the output list L3 in every recursive call and do the same with the rest until it has one element. The clause `bigger([],[]).` is useful only when the input is the empty list. When input is not empty the recursion stops when one element has left in the list. Also it is better to use `->` for the if-else statement.

The result:

```
?- bigger([1,2,6,8,5], X).
X = [2, 6, 8, 8, 5] ;
false.
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But a couple of things leave me confused.
How does bigger([H],[H]). stop the recursion exactly? It means both variables only have one element in the list, right? I understand that the first input list only has one left (since we keep making it smaller in the recursion), but isn't the second one (X) getting bigger? Shouldn't it have more than one element?

Comment: We follow the same thing as in the input, watch that the output list is also getting smaller and we force it to have one element when one element remains in the input. The output list is getting smaller because it is [X|T1] and we call  bigger([H2|T], T1) so it is getting smaller by one element in every recursion.

Comment: Okay, I think I am am starting to understand. Very interesting, I was looking at it very much backwards and trying to add to a list, but instead we need to indeed work it the same way we do the input list. Thank you.

Comment: Yes exactly, it is very common in such problems where you need to build the list based on the input, glad that helped!!